# map ssh connection through localhost

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I am not sure if what I  am trying to do is possible but I am trying to make a SSH connection go through localhost  with port forwarding.

The reason I want to do it is that I have some configuration on a cloud provider where an instance gets a different IP address every time it gets initialised and this means I have to change a few settings on my development environment at every run. I was wondering if I can somehow guide it through some static localhost setting, I could make it a  bit less tedious.

So, at the moment, I can connect as follows and I added some port forwarding as:

```
ssh luca@34.76.151.198 -L2222:localhost:2222
```

My hope was that I could then do something like:

```
ssh luca@localhost -p 2222
```

but this comes with the error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I am surprised, it is not a connection refused or time out or anything, so I wonder if this is some setting issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have some configuration on a cloud provider where an instance gets a different IP address every time it gets initialised and this means I have to change a few settings on my development environment at every run. I was wondering if I can somehow guide it through some static localhost setting, I could make it a bit less tedious.

The usual method for solving this problem is... DNS. Create a subdomain with very low TTL and update its A/AAAA records to point to the new instance whenever it is recreated. Some cloud providers might even be able to automate this.

(If global DNS doesn't work, then /etc/hosts would also work.)

> So, at the moment, I can connect as follows and I added some port forwarding as:
>
> ```
> ssh luca@34.76.151.198 -L2222:localhost:2222
> ```

Your remote server probably is not configured to listen for SSH connections on port 2222. It is only configured for the standard port 22. So the forwarding option you wanted is:

`-L 2222:localhost:22`

Here `2222` is the port that'll be open on your computer, and `localhost:22` is the final destination that the server will try to connect to.

> I am surprised, it is not a connection refused or time out or anything, so I wonder if this is some setting issue.

SSH `-L` forwarding doesn't work at packet level like your router's port forwarding. It works at TCP level – the client *itself* listens for connections, and whenever it receives one, it asks the server to connect to the final destination.

So there are 3 chained connections: client #2 → client #1 → server → destination.

This means that if the server fails to connect, client #1 (performing the forwarding) cannot possibly produce a "Connection refused" error for client #2 because the local connection has in fact been *accepted* already. The only thing it can do is close the existing connection without transferring any data. Hence "Connection reset by peer".

Comment: Thank you for that  clear explanation.